# How to show actual time elapsed across clock change in given timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta

How can i accurately reflect elapsed time at the point when 'Europe/London' time changes from BST to GMT?

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

x = datetime(year=2019, month=10, day=27, hour=1, minute=55, tzinfo=timezone('Europe/London'))

i = 0

while i<10:
    x = x + timedelta(minutes=1)
    print(x)
    i+=1
```

I kind of expected the output to show the hour jumping back at 2:00am as this is what will actually happen from the perspective of the 'Europe/London' timezone.

However, Output:

```
2019-10-27 01:56:00-00:01
2019-10-27 01:57:00-00:01
2019-10-27 01:58:00-00:01
2019-10-27 01:59:00-00:01
2019-10-27 02:00:00-00:01
2019-10-27 02:01:00-00:01
2019-10-27 02:02:00-00:01
2019-10-27 02:03:00-00:01
2019-10-27 02:04:00-00:01
2019-10-27 02:05:00-00:01
```

How can I show that at this time, if one minute elapses, the new time in that timezone will actually be 59 minutes earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to calculate in (explicit) UTC and parse to a specific timezone at printing/output:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

x = datetime(year=2019, month=10, day=27, hour=1, minute=55).astimezone(timezone('UTC'))

i = 0
while i<10:
    x = x + timedelta(minutes=1)
    print(x.astimezone(timezone('Europe/London')))
    i+=1
```

Returns:

```
2019-10-27 01:56:00+01:00
2019-10-27 01:57:00+01:00
2019-10-27 01:58:00+01:00
2019-10-27 01:59:00+01:00
2019-10-27 01:00:00+00:00
2019-10-27 01:01:00+00:00
2019-10-27 01:02:00+00:00
2019-10-27 01:03:00+00:00
2019-10-27 01:04:00+00:00
2019-10-27 01:05:00+00:00
```